# Linked List destructor in C++: should I delete?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I've start implementing some data structures in C++, starting from Linked Lists.
Coming from a Java background, I'm still wrapping my head around pointers and objects lifespans.

**LinkedList:**

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    int length;

public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();

    void addToHead(Node &newHead);
    void popHead();

    void printList();
};
```

and then I've implemented it like this:

```
LinkedList::LinkedList()
{ 
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    length = 0;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList(){}

void LinkedList::addToHead(Node& newHead)
{
    newHead.next = head;
    head = &newHead;
    length++;
}

void LinkedList::popHead()
{
    Node *currHead = head;
    head = head->next;
    length--;
}

void LinkedList::printList()
{
    Node *curr = head;

    while(curr)
    {
        curr = curr->next;  
    }
}
```

Lastly there's a simple main:

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList list;
    Node n1 = {3};
    Node n2 = {4};
    Node n3 = {5};
    list.addToHead(n1);
    list.addToHead(n2);
    list.addToHead(n3);
    list.printList();
    list.popHead();
    list.printList();

    return 0;
}
```

This a rather naive implementation, and I was wondering if I had to provide a proper destructor which deletes the Node* pointers upon iteration. 
Whenever I've tried to add it, the program results in a memory error, and I was thinking that the memory being allocated is being also deallocated at the end of the main, since all the Node*s live there.

*Should I fix my destructor? Should I change the whole interface?*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `delete` is for things created with `new`.

Comment: So the Node*s are going to be destroyed when the main() has finished running..? I'm just trying to understand if I'm leaking any memory here

Comment: @user in other words, if you did not use `new`, you don't have to use `delete`. If you didn't use `new`, there is no possibility for memory leaks in your sample

Comment: @user49428 `n1`, `n2`, and `n3` are created on the stack (i.e., not with `new`) so when they go out of scope the memory they used is made available. Note, the list class holds a pointer to the nodes and **the nodes could be destroyed before the list** which would leave your list in a bad state (dangling pointers).

Comment: Not strictly about your problem, but it seems you are learning C++98 / C++03. You're probably better off learning C++11 – there's also C++14, but that only fixed a few small oversights from C++11 so literature about C++11 isn't outdated while I'd definitely call C++98 / C++03 that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there are no memory leaks in your code as it stands, I think you should change your interface.

Your linked list isn't doing what you probably think its doing - taking ownership of its contents. A linked list that doesn't own its contents is a strange beast and probably something you did not intend.

One easy way to make it take ownership is to change your design to use `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers. Your `addToHead` function would then be change to take `std::unique_ptr` r-value references pointers (or simply raw pointers that create new `std::unique_ptr` internally if that's too advanced)

Here is your implementation changed to use `std::unique_ptr`. Its a bit rough-and-ready, but should get you on your way:

```
#include <memory>

struct Node
{
    Node(int i) : data(i) 
    {}

    int data;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Node> head;
    Node *tail;
    int length;

public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();

    void addToHead(std::unique_ptr<Node>&& newHead);
    void popHead();

    void printList();
};

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{ 
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    length = 0;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList(){}

void LinkedList::addToHead(std::unique_ptr<Node>&& newHead)
{
    newHead->next = std::move(head);
    head = std::move(newHead);
    length++;
}

void LinkedList::popHead()
{
    head = std::move(head->next);
    length--;
}

void LinkedList::printList()
{
    auto* curr = head.get();

    while(curr)
    {
        curr = curr->next.get();  
    }
}

int main()
{
    LinkedList list;
    list.addToHead(std::make_unique<Node>(3));
    list.addToHead(std::make_unique<Node>(4));
    list.addToHead(std::make_unique<Node>(5));
    list.printList();
    list.popHead();
    list.printList();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: any suggestions on what kind of modifications it needs? =)

Comment: There's a good tutorial implementation [here](https://github.com/Karlina-Bytes/LinkedList_Tutorial).

Comment: NULL should be replaced with nullptr

Comment: This feels like the first time popHead() is called it will delete the entire list. Or else the popped entries will leak.

Comment: I can see why you think it 'feels' like that but that won't happen. In a `unique_ptr` assignment operation, the 'move' of the rhs happens before the delete of the old lhs - it has to be this way round, for exception safety. So by the time the old head is destroyed, it no longer owns its `next` - this has been moved to the new head.